# How to add a legend to the map using react leaflet, without using refs and manually modifying the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet and want to add a legend to the map.

I can currently do it by passing a ref of the map to a custom component and render null while having a function create the HTML and add it to the map. The refs are being a nightmare to test using Jest and Enzyme.

Is there a way to using a react-leaflet component to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve that by extending `react-leaflet`'s `MapControl` class and using for instance the legend code provided by Leaflet official page tutorial for [Using GeoJSON with Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

```
class Legend extends MapControl {
   componentDidMount() {
      // place your code here

      ...
      const legend = L.control({ position: "bottomright" });

      ...
      const { map } = this.props.leaflet;
      legend.addTo(map);
   }
}
```

and then import it here:

```
 <Map style={{ height: "100vh" }} center={position} zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        <Legend />
 </Map>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-add-a-legend-to-the-map-using-react-leaflet-6yqs5)

Comment: Thanks @kboul! This works. Is there documentation pertaining to this? I'd like to understand some aspects of this a little more and have some other stuff I need to change from imperative to declarative in React for leaflet.

Comment: Only [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html) but there in not much info, nevertheless a start.

Comment: Would you have any pointers on how to test that a child component is being rendered on the map? I'm using Enzyme and Jest.

Comment: TS says there's no call signature on L.control
Did something change?

Comment: Not sure. Haven't tested it with typescript.

Comment: It thorws error on unmount says no function named remove() found